# Storing Email in S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, mime-message, aws-java-sdk

I would like to store an email in an S3 bucket just as is done by an SES Rule Set action (as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html)

In order to do this, I was thinking of generating a MimeMessage Object and then putting it into the S3 bucket with the help of the SDK:

```
MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
emailMessage.setFrom()
emailMessage.setContent()...
```

And then:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client...
s3Client.putObject(bucketName, key, emailMessage.getInputStream(), metadata);
```

Is this necessary? To build the `MimeMessage` Object only to take it apart into an `InputStream` when inserting into the S3 bucket?
If not, how can I create an identical `InputStream` (to when it is done by an SES Rule Set action) without first creating the `MimeMessage` Object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is over 4 years old at this point, but perhaps this will help for people who stumble upon this question as I did: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/setup-email-receiving-pipeline/